# View localization on .NET MVC Core when the view's parent directory structure is different to the name of its controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have been restructuring my .NET MVC Core project to make it easier to manage. A simplified version of my project is as follows:

```
Controllers/
    CatController.cs
    DogController.cs
Resources/
    Views/
        Cat/
            Index.en-CY.resx
        Dog/
            Index.en-CY.resx
Views/
    Cat/
        Index.cshtml
    Dog/
        Index.cshtml
```

Localization works great with this structure, but the structure itself (in the real project) is difficult to navigate.

The new structure is as follows:

```
Controllers/
    Animal/
        Cat/
            CatController.cs
        Dog/
            DogController.cs
        AbstractAnimalController.cs
Resources/
    Views/
        Animal/
            Cat/
                Index.en-CY.resx
            Dog/
                Index.en-CY.resx
Views/
    Animal/
        Cat/
            Index.cshtml
        Dog/
            Index.cshtml
```

However this structure breaks the view localization. Specifically, the view no longer uses the resource file, displaying the keys when it previously displayed the values.

I have narrowed down the issue to being that the controller name is still `CatController`, but the location of the `Cat` view is now `Animal/Cat/Index.cshtml`.

Localization works if I keep my views and resources in the old structure, but I'd rather be able to keep it consistent with the `Controllers` directory structure.

Localization is done using `@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer` in each of the views. According to Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#resource-file-naming), when using an IViewLocalizer in a view, the resource should either have the same directory structure as the view or use representative dot notation. It does not specify that the view must be in a directory named for its controller, which is what I'm finding here.

Is this a bug with .NET Core, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try to remove the "Views" folder under "Resources", seems redundant and confusing IMHO.

Comment: @Isma, as far as I know, having a `Views` folder under `Resources` for view localization is standard practice (see [aspnet example](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Localization.StarterWeb)). I'll try that anyhow :)

Comment: You are right, seems the correct way.

Comment: I guess this is the default behavior for views and you can't change it. One solution I can think of is you can use [Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas). In your example, you create `Animal` area and inside it you create two folders one for controllers and the other for views. Than inside `Resources` folder, create `Areas` folder and inside it create the same structure as `Animal ` area you created before and put your resources files.